# multiway desktop screen sharing app for linux

Tags: linux, screen-sharing

Is there a free screen sharing app for linux ? I'm not talking about controling a desktop from remote, but simply viewing someone else's screen, quite useful for a teleconference.

The newest version of Skype has a "share screen" feature that uses its webcam channel, it's not bad but the picture quality is rather low so it's actually difficult to the see the details... and actually it's impossible to read text... Also, it's only on the windows version.

I recently found mikogo which seems really nice but again, only for windows or mac

Anything like that for linux ?

Dav

Comment: Your question is better suited for superuser.com

Answer (score 3):

I'd just use **[VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC)**. You can share screens without giving the other party control of your desktop.

Answer (score 3):

VNC is what you want.   A default Ubuntu install provides the *vino* server that's part of the GNOME project (other distributions' GNOME desktops may or may not include *vino*).  There are other VNC servers that can also do the job, in particular [*x11vnc*](http://www.karlrunge.com/x11vnc/).

Here's how to configure Vino in Ubuntu.  Access System -> Preferences -> Remote Desktop:

[image]

- Check *"Allow other users to view your desktop"*
- **Uncheck** *"Allow other users to control your desktop"*
- Set the confirmation if desired
- Set a password if desired (you'll need to share this with your guests ahead of time -- it does not need to be, and shouldn't be, the same as the password you use to log in)

([source](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/share-your-ubuntu-desktop-using-remote-desktop.html))

Your guests can use any VNC viewer they like to connect with your computer at **computer-name:0** or **x.x.x.x:0** (replace *x.x.x.x* with your computer's IP address).

Comment: Works! I was able to connect to a CentOS PC via Windows and via Linux using TigerVNC. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with www.logmein.com a linux user can view a windows or Mac computer.

For the other way around modern Linux desktops have the vino server for providing remote desktop sharing/viewing.

Comment: vino is just the VNC server software used in some/most GNOME installs.  (Ubuntu installs it by default, so that's what gets enabled when you "allow remote access to your desktop".)  there are lots of other VNC server options besides vino.